# detection of logged in users asp.net webapi + angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am currently exploring ways to detect the number of logged in users in an asp.net web api/angularjs application.

My current approach would be to pull the server using javascript every n seconds. Is this an acceptable approach? Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

PS:

Found [this](http://www.deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/get-the-number-of-users-that-are-online-using-signalr/1095) see naswer below - might be of interest for others ...

Comment: If you vote it down be so kind and least provide some constructive feedback!

Comment: You can use Signlr. I do not know if that is appropriate or not

Comment: Thanks - any links with examples would be very much appreciated (google did not help much).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SignalR has OnConnected, OnDisconnected, methods you can override them.

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    //broadcast to all connected clients. in your case telling client side to increment 
    //by one.
    return base.OnConnected();
}

public override Task OnDisconnected()
{
    //same as above but decrement 
    return base.OnDisconnected();
}
```

And for introduction on Signlr with angular.
[Signlr with angular](http://henriquat.re/server-integration/signalr/integrateWithSignalRHubs.html)

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any ideas how this scales if there are let us say 1000 users online? Thanks.

Comment: You can read that http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-in-signalr

Comment: So are you saying I should scale out just to be able to detect whether users are still logged in?

Comment: the last article is about performance. however if you want to know when a user get logged out the on disconnected method fires logged out her means closing browser

Comment: does this mean that the client does not constantly send messages to the backend or how does this work?

Comment: Signlr is a web socket technology that enables your clients or console application to have two way communications as your are not restricted to the idea of making a request and response that HTTP fallows for example you can use signalr for implementing notification system or chat application and for more information that covers how signlr works http://www.asp.net/signalr and also for a real example http://shootr.signalr.net/

Comment: And for a video tutorial her is a very good one that covers most of  signlr capabilities https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GjGXF-7liOU

Comment: I have a rough understanding what signalr is and what you can do with it. The question is how does it achieve OnDisconnected. Surely the client frontend must make some notifications to the backend to notify it that the page is still being 'looked at' by the user (i.e. the user is logged in). The problem I see is scalability (there will be many notifications if there are many users 'logged in').